# How to send hashtag to telegram using requests?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I want to send `#` before my text to telegram using requests method, but always get an error, I tried using `%23` buy doesn't work.

```
def sendMsg(text):
     token = BOT_TOKEN
     id = CHANNEL_ID
     requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token + "/sendMessage?chat_id="+id+"&text="+text)

sendMsg('#Hello')
```

If I use `%23` I receive the message like this: `%23Hello`

Answer (score 0):

Only now checked,
It works

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

def send_mes(mes):
 token="my_token"
 id="my_id"
 requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot_id:'+token, data={"chat_id":id,"text":mes})

send_mes("#my_message")
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: please show error

Comment: I believe it's missing the name of the telegram endpoint. This should work: `f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage"`